# Não consigo enviar e-mail para minha WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Eu estou tentando criar uma função na minha *WebApi* onde retorno informações com base no endereço de e-mail que eu envio, o problema é que o caractere "." quebra a rota.

No caso eu fiz minha action assim:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[Route("Usuarios/GetUsuarioPorEmail/{email}")]
public IQueryable<Usuarios> GetUsuarioPorEmail(string email)
```

Tentei chamar de todas essas formas e nenhuma funcionou,
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/teste@teste.com
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/?teste@teste.com
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/=teste@teste.com
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/email=teste@teste.com
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/?email=teste@teste.com

Mas se eu chamar assim, funciona
http://localhost:11111/api/Usuarios/GetUsuariosPorEmail/teste@testecom

Só que não existe e-mail sem ponto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar este cenário, inclua uma barra ao final da rota. Essa implementação delimitará o parâmetro `email` entre as duas barras e não considerará o mesmo como parte do domínio.

```
[Route("Usuarios/GetUsuarioPorEmail/{email}/")]
public IQueryable<Usuarios> GetUsuarioPorEmail(string email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[Route("api/Usuarios/GetUsuarioPorEmail")]
public IQueryable<Usuarios> GetUsuarioPorEmail(string email)
{
}
```

e chame no para teste assim:

```
http://localhost:80/api/Usuarios/GetUsuarioPorEmail?email=a@ig.com.br
```

resultado se fosse imprimir o e-mail:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja, um parametro `get`, claro que após esse recebimento, uma validação de e-mail é requerida para não ter problemas com dados inválidos.